# error during jhipster upgrade

Tags: node.js, gulp, upgrade, jhipster

I want to upgrade my jhipster version from 4.8.2 to 4.9.0.

When I launch updgrade, I have this error :

```
C:\Users\VLR\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\semver\semver.js:279
throw new TypeError('Invalid Version: ' + version);
^
TypeError: Invalid Version: undefined
at new SemVer (C:\Users\VLR\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\semver\semver.js:279:11)
at compare (C:\Users\VLR\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\semver\semver.js:566:10)
at Function.lt (C:\Users\VLR\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\semver\semver.js:600:10)
at shelljs.exec (C:\Users\VLR\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\upgrade\index.js:152:28)
at C:\Users\VLR\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\shelljs\src\exec.js:199:9
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:189:7)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)`
```

I am on Windows 10 Pro, with version of solution :

- npm : 3.10.10
- node : V6.11.2
- gulp : CLI 3.9.1
- yarn : 0.27.5

have you an idea for solve this errror?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understand my problem
I must do upgrade in jhipster project and it works !!